# sharepoint-show some data of list in page For example number of item added to list

Tags: list, data

I want to show summary of data of list in page.
 For example number of item added to list or number of item that created with each users.
 Is it possible?
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your can use Xslt List View Web part and configure view for it. For example, you can group by creator.

[Create, change, or delete a view of a list or library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-HA102774516.aspx)

Comment: what is Xslt List View Web part ?

Comment: Sory, looks like I used developer's words:)
When you click add Web Part in Web Part page you see category List and Libraries. This is Xslt List View Web Part configured to display some list or library.